# Iterate through nested lists in pandas column and create dictionary based on values in nested lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like:

```
id        some_binary_col        some_amount_col        nested_lists
123       0                      100                    ['email_rule','phone_rule','score_rule']
456       1                      500                    ['address_rule','zip_rule']
121       1                      300                    ['zip_rule','phone_rule']
122       0                      100                    ['score_rule','phone_rule','new_rule']
133       1                      200                    ['email_rule','address_rule','zip_rule']
```

reproducible:

```
ids = [123,456,121,122,133]
some_binary_col = [0,1,1,0,1]
some_amount_col = [100,500,300,100,200]
nested_lists = [
    ['email_rule','phone_rule','score_rule']
    ,['address_rule','zip_rule']
    ,['zip_rule','phone_rule']
    ,['score_rule','phone_rule','new_rule']
    ,['email_rule','address_rule','zip_rule']
]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['id'] = ids
df['some_binary_col'] = some_binary_col
df['some_amount_col'] = some_amount_col
df['nested_lists'] = nested_lists
```

I'm trying to make a new dictionary that counts the `some_binary_col` if = 1 per rule in the `nested_loop` col like:

```
rule_binary_col_dict = {
    'email_rule': 1
    ,'phone_rule': 1
    ,'score_rule': 0
    ,'address_rule': 2
    ,'zip_rule': 3
    ,'new_rules': 0
}
```

The `nested_list` can have infinite unique lists/elements.

What I'm not very good at is looping through each element in the nested list...
like:

```
for i in df['nested_lists']:
    for j in i:
        **some condition**
```

I don't know how to get to each element in the nested lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data frame and the desired output dictionary.

```
rule_binary_col_dict = {} 

for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
    # List of rules
    for rule in row.nested_lists:
        # count to 0 if the rule is not in the dictionary
        if rule not in rule_binary_col_dict:
            rule_binary_col_dict[rule] = 0
        # Increment the count if some_binary_col is 1
        if row.some_binary_col == 1:
            rule_binary_col_dict[rule] += 1
        
# Print the result
print(rule_binary_col_dict)
```

Output

```
{'email_rule': 1, 'phone_rule': 1, 'score_rule': 0, 'address_rule': 2, 'zip_rule': 3, 'new_rule': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the options would be [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)/[`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) & [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) :

```
ser = df["nested_lists"].explode()

rule_binary_col_dict = (
    ser.loc[df["some_binary_col"].eq(1)].value_counts()
        .reindex(ser.unique(), fill_value=0).to_dict()
)
```

Output :

```
print(rule_binary_col_dict)

{'email_rule': 1,
 'phone_rule': 1,
 'score_rule': 0,
 'address_rule': 2,
 'zip_rule': 3,
 'new_rule': 0}
```